# Django Как передать переменную из views.py, которая содержит текст на html шаблон?

Tags: python, html, django

Django Как передать переменную из views.py, которая содержит текст на html шаблон ?

Comment: Через контекст.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(request):
    context = {'text_variable': 'Текст для шаблона'}
    return render(request, '<путь до шаблона>.html', context)
```

подробней о view можно почитать в официальной документации
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/

Answer (score 0):

Если во views.py Вы используете классы тогда переменные передаются вот так:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # здесь передаем переменную с именем name_variable
        # и ее значением value_variable
        context['name_variable'] = "value_variable"
        return context
```